# Aquamac, AUCTeX should open PDF in external viewer, not render it in Emacs buffer

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex

I use AUCTeX in my Mac Emacs, which is Aquamac 23.1.

Typically in AUCTeX, when I type `C-c C-c` it runs `pdflatex`, then `C-c C-c` again and it opens it in a PDF viewer. But in this Aquamac emacs version, it renders the PDF right in the emacs buffer.

How can I change that? I just want it to open the PDF in a PDF viewer (ideally, [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/)) when I press `C-c C-c`.

Comment: I think that Aquamacs (version 2.0 (or 2.1?) by the way: 23.1 is the GNU Emacs version on which it is based) should read the system's default application to open PDF files out of the box without any need for customisation.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know whether it is going to work, but try the following:

```
M-x customize-apropos RET
```

then write:

```
tex-view-program RET
```

This will bring two customisable options:

`tex-view-program-selection` and `tex-view-program-list`.

This is how I have set them

[image]

The most important, I think, is the one I circled in red. If you click on the button `value menu` it should give you the option to put Skim.

Remember to save your options by clicking on `set for current session` and `set for future sessions`, on the top of this same screen. If it doesn't work, try re-starting Emacs (after having saved the options, of course).

**EDIT**: If you can't find it using the `customize-apropos` command, you can use the menu as shown here:

[image]

Then scroll down until you find the options I mentioned above, i.e. `tex-view-program-selection` and `tex-view-program-list`, and change then accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. I don't have `tex-view-program` though: `No customizable items matching tex-view-program`.

Comment: @dehmann: are you sure you wrote it exactly as it is? with the hyphens rather than space, and with no space at the end? In any case, I have updated my answer, that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize Auctex:
LaTeX -> Customize AucTeX -> TeX Command -> TeX Output View Style

Click view, change the viewer for `^pdf` extension, "safe" for future sessions on the top and you are done.

Comment: Hmm, where is the LaTeX menu? I only see a TeX menu, with items `TeX File`, `TeX Buffer`, `Validate Buffer` etc.

Comment: @dehmann: Are you sure you are using AucTeX and not the default TeX mode bundled with emacs?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure anymore. I thought it's automatically using AucTex, because the C-c C-c command kind of works, although in a different way than I'm used to. I'll check ...

Answer (score 0):

AUCTeX actually has code for handling viewers on darwin system but somehow it is commented out. I have been using the following patch in AUCTeX: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/250752/ and haven't found a problem. I will find time to encourage upstream to do the same.